# How to obtain query arg from Dropwizard's /healthcheck HTTP call?

Tags: jax-rs, dropwizard

Dropwizard's doc shows how a service can define a healthcheck that can be called with :

`https://<hostname>:<port>/health-check?type=<type>&name=<name>`

But I can not find in the docs how a class implementing such checks ( extending HealthCheck )  can receive these query args.

I expected @QueryParam() to be useable or the query args being available